# Three Xs show when using sIFR on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, sifr

I have been using sIFR on a production website, and it unfortunately renders incorrectly in IE8. I have removed sIFR from the live version, but it is still visible on the staging version.

Interestingly, sIFR is used in a couple of places on the page. At the top it replaces the title with:

```
X
X
X
```

and throws an error in IE. Elsewhere on the page it simply degrades as would normally happen on a non-flash enabled browser.

Any idea why this is happening? The error is:

> 1.bottom is null or not an object' in sifr.js, line 19 character 14132

Comment: I'm not sure (yet) what is happening but I do know IE has issues with back to back comments... which I see in the generated source: <!-- Displaying News Module --><!-- News Categories: '' --><!-- Start News Display Template -->  you may want to consider removing these or ensuring they don't occur back-to-back

Comment: What version of sifr? Alot of people are having issues with the beta version of sifr when running IE8 in normal browser mode. In Compat View it works. A hack is to set this meta-tag: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

Comment: actually, you're embedding an Object tag in an H1 tag... since that isn't really a "phrase" element (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html) is IE8 rejecting it? e.g. if you move it outside the H1 tag does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The pages renders OK in IE8 compatibility view (where it emulates IE7). You can force this behavior by including the following in your header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

As IE7 is the "broken" mode the next step is to figure out why the page doesn't render properly in IE8 mode, but perhaps it is being "too smart" and doesn't realize that IE8 is more standards compliant.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem a while ago and have been searching for a solution.

I finally solved my problem, hopefully it will solve yours.

http://blog.clintonbeattie.com/sifr3-ie8-problem-and-solution/

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question which sIFR version you are using, but this problem should not occur in r436.